# Android device doesn't recognize file in index.html IonicFramework/Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, photoeditorsdk

I'm trying to develop a project with IonicFramework and Cordova. Problem is that I have .js file that added as script element in index.html file of project below the line I added app.js. `<script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.min.js"></script>`
This file is inside the www/js. This file is recognized by browser, iOS emulator and device and Android emulator, but not Android device. It gives this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PhotoEditorSDK is not defined, http://192.168.1.4:8100/js/controllers.js, Line: 297
```

Please help me! Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
Edit:
Here is my related part of controller.js code:

```
$scope.openEditor = function(){
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.showSettings = false;
  });

  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = imageSrc;
  myImage.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('editor');
        var editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
        preferredRenderer: 'canvas',
        container: container,
        title: 'Pixel',
        showCloseButton: true,
        showNewButton: true,
        maxMegaPixels: {
        mobile: 20
        },
        export:{
          showButton: true,
          type: PhotoEditorSDK.RenderType.DATAURL,
          download: false
        },
        image: myImage,
          assets: {
            baseUrl: 'assets/'
          }
        });

        editor.on('close', function () {
          editor.dispose();
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.showSettings = true;
            $cordovaGoogleAds.showInterstitial();
          });
        });

        editor.on('export', function (result) {
          saveToPhotoLibrary(result);
        });
  });
}
```

Comment: Post your controllers.js code please.

Comment: Make sure the casing of the filename is correct. Android takes this very serious :)

Comment: Can you unzip apk file and check if there is PhotoEditorSDK.min.js present in www folder?